# updating Dictionary code with ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

How to update the following code to use a ConcurrentDictionary?

```
private Dictionary (string, SymbolOrderBook) books = new Dictionary(string, SymbolOrderBook)();

SymbolOrderBook book;

lock (books)
{
    if (!books.TryGetValue(symbol, out book))
    {
        book = new SymbolOrderBook(symbol);
        books.Add(symbol, book);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what are you struggling with that is stopping you from doing it yourself? Also we can't convert that because that is not valid code. For example is `book` local to the function or is it a class level varible? Please show the method declration.

Comment: Take a look at the [GetOrAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`GetOrAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

First, you define the dictionary like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, SymbolOrderBook> books =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SymbolOrderBook>();
```

And then you get or add an entry like this:

```
SymbolOrderBook book = books.GetOrAdd(symbol, s => new SymbolOrderBook(s));
```

What this does is that it either returns an existing book if it exists for the specified symbol, or else, it creates a new one, adds it to the dictionary, and then returns it. All that happens in an atomic operation.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

ConcurrentDictionary<string, SymbolOrderBook> books = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SymbolOrderBook>();
SymbolOrderBook book = new SymbolOrderBook(symbol);
books.GetOrAdd(symbol, book);
```

Comment: Personally I would use the overload that takes in a `Func<string, SymbolOrderBook>` that way you are not creating a new book unless you need to. Also it is not clear from the OP's code if `book` is used later on in the code, your current answer would make `book` be a new value every time and would never get the stored value.